# how do i rotate sprite when pressing left or right

Tags: godot, gdscript

I tried looking at serveral tutorials, but i didnt understand

```
`#car driving
func get_car_input():
    var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    var speed = 500
    if Input.is_action_pressed("forward"):
        velocity.y = -1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("backward"):
        velocity.y = 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        velocity.x = -1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        velocity.x = 1
    move_and_slide(velocity*speed)`
```

Comment: I meant when input is changed

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74294605/edit) the question to add clarifications. Addendum: you might also be interested in [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 1):

A few corrections...

First, the `input(event)` method of nodes runs when input is detected, and `unhandled_input(event)` when input not handled by other nodes reaches this one. But move and slide is a function you probably want inside `process(delta)` or `physichs_process(delta)` to run on every frame.

You can, however, get around it by just doing:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed = 500
var input_vector = Vector2.ZERO


func _process(_delta):
    input_vector = Vector2(Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left"),
                                Input.get_action_strength("ui_down") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_up")).normalized()
        
    move_and_slide(input_vector * speed)
```

By the way make shure you are using a KinematicBody node with the collision properly set since `move_and_slide()` is an KinematicBody method.

Also make shure you arecorrectly referencing the action names on Input calls. You can see them in Project Settings > Input Map.

#### Addendum

If you want to **rotate** the sprite you dont need `move_and_slide()`. Use `self.rotate()` or `self.rotation`.

Answer (score 0):

For another alternative on your code:

```
    var speed := 500.0
    var velocity := Vector2(
        Input.get_axis("left", "right"),
        Input.get_axis("forward", "backward")
    ) * speed
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

For reference `Input.get_axis("left", "rght")` is equivalent to:

```
Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left")
```

*There is also `Input.get_vector`, it differs in that it has a circulad dead zone, while the above approach has a cross deadzone.*

---

About the rotation, you can set `rotation` or call `rotate`. For example:

```
    var rotation_speed := 3.0
    var rotation_velocity := Input.get_axis("left", "right") * rotation_speed
    rotate(rotation_velocity * delta)
```

Unlike `move_and_slide` you need to multiply by `delta`. The reason is that `move_and_slide` takes a velocity (which I remind you is displacement over time), but `rotate` taken an angle (in radians, by the way) not an angular velocity.

---

Now, presumably you want the forwards and backward motion to be in the rotated direction. But `move_and_slide` is in global units. First of all, that means we are not going to use left and right for the velocity, and second it means we need to rotate the velocity vector according our current rotation.

We can do that like this:

```
    var speed := 500.0
    var velocity := Vector2(0.0, Input.get_axis("forward", "backward")) * speed
    velocity = velocity.rotated(rotation)
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```